# set the border of text input to none

Tags: css

How to set only the border of text input to `none` using `fes-name-value`

```
<tr class="fes-single-variation">
    <td class="fes-name-row">
        <input type="text" class="fes-name-value" name="option[0][description]" id="options[0][description]" rows="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="fes-price-row">
        <input type="text" class="fes-price-value" name="option[0][price]" id="options[0][price]" value="0">
    </td>
    <td class="fes-delete-row">
        <a href="#" class="edd-fes-delete">
            ×
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

This is the css that maybe related to that

```
    media="all"
#edd_checkout_form_wrap input.edd-input, #edd_checkout_form_wrap input[type=email], #edd_checkout_form_wrap input[type=password], #edd_checkout_form_wrap input[type=text], #edd_checkout_form_wrap textarea, #edd_checkout_form_wrap textarea.edd-input, .marketify-input, input[type=search], input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=password], input[type=number], textarea {
    color: #404040;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-siding: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this simple out? `.fes-name-value{border:none;}`

Comment: yes, but it did not work.

Comment: @John Try setting !important.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/s62rr8zg/

Comment: I added css file of the page. This css file is from chrome developer.

Comment: @John The formatting is all messed up.

Comment: In your new edit where is `.fes-name-value{border:none;}` used?

Comment: i did use that. it does not work. There is css code somewhere which controls it.

Comment: Here i used in your code and it's working. https://jsfiddle.net/vjg9b68b/ Either give link or check in developer tool by inspect element which css conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css selector like so:

```
.fes-name-value {
    border: 0;
}
```

or if you have other elements with the same class
but only want the textbox to change, do this:

```
input[type="text"][class="fes-name-value"] {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. The second choice works!